# Embed HTML page as header and footer to my HTML page (Subdomain)?

Tags: asp.net, html, cross-domain, dotnetnuke

I am doing a DNN (asp .net) website which is expected to run as a sub domain website to a parent website running on PHP. To explain it with an example I am building subdomain.example.com which is being built using asp .net technology (DotNetNuke) the example.com is running on PHP (I guess wordpress).

I have to embed a header (banner section http://example.com/header_section_only) and a footer (site map http://example.com/footer_section_only) from the parent website (example.com) to the sub-domain website (subdomain.example.com). As banner advertisement are dynamic in nature the height of header page might change on a day to day biases.

I had proposed to use IFrame but variable size of the page create a lot of problem, are there other solution to this problem? Can anyone suggest me other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use this way:

In your `index.php` or the main file, you can include the `header_section_only` this way:

```
<body>
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/header_section_only");
?>
<!-- Body Contents -->
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/footer_section_only");
?>
</body>
```

#### If the files are relatively present:

```
<body>
<?php
    include ("header.inc");
?>
<!-- Body Contents -->
<?php
    include ("footer.inc");
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, but I cannot use PHP as I am developing the site in ASP .net. The subdomain.example.com run on DNN (asp .net).

Comment: Okay, in case of ASP.net, you can see [How To Dynamically Include Files in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306575). Hope that helps. :)